# Vue: Rendered list show selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, rendering

I try to display my selected checkboxes, which I render like this:

```
 <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(selectedAttributes, null, 2) }}</pre>
            <ul
              class="list-unstyled"
              v-for="category in categories"
              :key="category.name"
            >
              <strong>{{ category.category_name }} </strong>
              <li
                v-for="attributes in category.attributes"
                :key="attributes.attribute_id"
              >
                <Field
                  as="input"
                  name="attribute"
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="form-check-input"
                  v-model="selectedAttributes"
                  :id="attributes.attribute_id"
                  :value="attributes.attribute_id"
                />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="attributes.attribute_id">
                  {{ attributes.attribute_name }}
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>

...

  data() {
    return {
      selectedAttributes: [],
    };
  },
```

Unfortunately, the attribute_id of my selected checkboxes is not showing. Where is my mistake?
[image]

**Update:** The data from my api looks like this: [image]

What I need here is, I want the user to check his preferred options and display the selected options in the JSON.stringify. The selectedAttributes should display the attribute_id of the chosen option.

Comment: Please provide more code and how your data looks like. It is unclear from this snippet. We don't see how your `categories` look like and what `selectedAtrributes` are there for

Comment: You are missing a `:` - it should be `:for="attributes.attribute_id"` otherwise it will match the literal string.

Comment: @match changed it, but the attribute_id's are still not showing

Comment: @VojinPurić I updated my post, hope this gives you more insight on what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data does not have `attribute_id` id property at all. Only `attribute_name` you can see at the image you provided

Comment: No problem glad I could help, upvote on an answer would be nice if you don't mind